# PowerShell: Output provider results from multiple Azure subscriptions into one .txt file - via arrayList

Tags: azure, powershell, arraylist

I am trying to get the registered providers for multiple subscriptions and output everything into **one file**.
For that, i am getting the subscriptions from a folder full of *.yaml files that contain information about the subscriptions, including their name.
What i cannot achieve is get the result for each subscriptions into an array and output that array into a text file. The script also allows the use of only one item from the folder in case that is the case.

Here is a sample code of a subscription and the code for it:

subscription1.yaml

```
name: subscription1
emailContact: email.address@domain.com
tags:
  - key: "key1"
    value: "Value1"
```

subscription2.yaml

```
name: subscription2
emailContact: email.address@domain.com
tags:
  - key: "key1"
    value: "Value1"
```

Folder structure where the yaml files is: `./landingZones/landingzone1/settings/dev/*.yaml`

script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$Environment = 'dev',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$LandingZoneType = 'landingzone1',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$SingleSubscription
)
$scriptPath = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath
$subscriptionsEnvironmentDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Directory $scriptPath -Recurse -Filter "*$Environment*" | Where-Object { $_.parent.parent.Name -eq $LandingZoneType }
$subscriptions = Get-ChildItem -Path $($subscriptionsEnvironmentDirectory.FullName)
foreach ($subscription in ($subscriptions | Where-Object { ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($SingleSubscription)) -or ($_.Name -replace "\.[^\.]+$", '') -eq $SingleSubscription })) {
    $landingZone = Get-Content -Path $subscription.FullName | ConvertFrom-Yaml
    # Set subscriptionName variable
    $subscriptionName = $landingZone.name

    $providers = az provider list --subscription $subscriptionName | ConvertFrom-Json 
    $defaultRegisteredProviders = 'Microsoft.ADHybridHealthService|Microsoft.Authorization|Microsoft.Billing|Microsoft.ClassicSubscription|Microsoft.Commerce|Microsoft.Consumption|Microsoft.CostManagement|Microsoft.Features|Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering'
    $registeredProviders = $providers | Where-Object { ($_.registrationState -eq 'Registered') -and ($_.namespace -notmatch $defaultRegisteredProviders) }

    # Outputting result into txt file in the same directory where the command was executed

    Write-Host ('{1}# Registered providers for subscription [{0}]' -f $subscriptionName, "`n")
    $list = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
    $sortedObjects = $registeredProviders | Sort-Object namespace | `
        Format-Table `
    @{l = 'Namespace'; e = { $_.namespace } }, `
    @{l = "Subscription Id [$subscriptionName]"; e = { $_.id } }, `
    @{l = 'Registration State'; e = { $_.registrationState } }, `
    @{l = 'Registration Policy'; e = { $_.registrationPolicy } }
    foreach ($i in $sortedObjects) {
        $list.Add($i) | Out-Null
    }
    # Alternative to add into array:
    # @($sortedObjects).foreach({$list.Add($_)}) | Out-Null
}
$list.Count
$list | Out-File  .\registered_providers.txt -Force
```

The result is a file called 'registered_providers.txt' that contains only the registered providers for the first subscription in the foreach loop. I cannot get the contents of the second, third and so on in the same file, just a replaced text from the `$sortedObjects`

How do i create the array to contain all the info from all the subscriptions called?

Thanks

Comment: Out-File has an append option.  Put the Out-File inside the for loop since you are creating a new list inside the loop use New-Object.

Comment: I am having a hard time understaing your comment. What do you mean by `use New-Object`?

Comment: You code is using : $list = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'  So everytime you go through loop $list is emptied.

Comment: `-Append` worked and i have a complete file now.

Comment: You are right about the `$list = New-Object`. Any idea on what to change?

Comment: You just need to put the $list | Out-File inside the for loop and use append.  Or put the New-Object before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`$list | Out-File` Should be inside the for loop so that all the data you are fetching will be stored in the specified file.

**Out-File** cmdlet has **`-append`** parameter that appends the output to the existing file for every for loop happens. Otherwise, it will clean up the information/value stored in that output file.

Thanks to @*jdweng* for pointing the user to the right solution.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.3) on Out-File -Append Parameter usage.